# Как распарсить и изменить содержимое большого XML-файла, используя iterparse()

Tags: python-3.x, xml

Здравствуйте.

Имеется **большой** xml файл 10+Gb, прочитать его каким либо способом кроме iterparse() не представляется возможным т.к. не хватает оперативной памяти.

Есть задача не только парсить\прочитать xml, но также изменять содержимое файла, с вставками нод после какого либо закрывающего тега.

Парсю примерно так:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -- coding: utf-8 -*-
from xml.etree.ElementTree import tostring
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.iterparse(filename, events=("start", "end",))
for event, elem in tree:
    if elem.tag == 'tag_which_needed' and event == 'start':
         #TODO делаем что то с информацией внутри тегов
    elem.clear()
```

Гуглил как изменить при таком подходе файл не нашел. Подскажите пожалуйста  куда копать, или может быть у кого то пример кода есть. Поделитесь опытом, буду признателен. Спасибо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399904/using-python-elementtrees-itertree-function-and-writing-modified-tree-to-output

Answer (score 2):

В простых случаях, многогигабайтные xml документы, которые в памяти не помещаются, могут быть последовательностью xml элементов, которые уже в памяти помещаются. Чтобы изменить документ, вы читаете эти элементы, изменяете если нужно, и сохраняете по одному элементу за раз. [Пример кода](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15457389/4279).

В более общем случае, можно попробовать загрузить ваш xml в настоящую базу данных (e.g., PostgreSQL). Выполнить произвольные изменения уже в БД и экспортировать в xml, если необходимо. Посмотрите, не имеет ли смысл вообще xml потерять и работать только с БД или использовать append-only формат (чтобы любые изменения только в конец  файла шли).